# Handling external C++ dependencies

Tags: c++, git, cmake

The project structure we used to use was that code + prebuild external dependencies were source controlled in SVN. This was cumbersome because the external libraries were large and didn't need to be source controlled since they were prebuilt binaries.

Now we have source in git and the prebuilt binaries are in the cloud. The dev has to download this lib folder from the cloud after cloning the repo. Problem here is that if you make changes to lib then things will not build correctly until the developer goes and redownloads this lib folder.

Our projects are generally developed for Windows (MSVC) but we just added Linux (GCC+Docker) compatibility and likely in the future Linux will be the main version. So now our libraries each have a Windows and a Linux build folder. Our dev environments are Windows + VSCode/WSL2/Docker for Linux.

What is the best, common practice here for handling external dependencies. I can think of 2 ways.

- Version the lib folder in the cloud and check that during building. If Developer A adds/changes this and updates the CMakeLists file then when Developer B updates his git repo and tries to build then CMake can see that the version of the libs folder he has is out of date and will be told to go update that. This is little effort and changes almost nothing of our process. Cons are that Developer A has to remember to update the version in both the cloud and in the cmake check.
- Build all external libraries locally. Use git submodules and have cmake build all dependencies while building the main project. I assume there's a way to cache it so it doesn't rebuild constantly (some of these libraries are large and take a long time to build). More work, but less maintenance and needing of extra developer steps. Also probably easier to link and include against.

Comment: There are "binary repositories" allowing you to store versions with a tag such as "latest". If this server does also allow for querying the version info you could probably write a find module that checks the version of the lib on the server against the currenlty locally used version stored via cache entries and simply replace the lib version with the new one downloaded from the server, if required.

Comment: "Build everything from source at the same time with the same flags if possible."
— Titus Winters, PacificPlusPlus 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem here is that if you make changes to lib then things will not build correctly until the developer goes and redownloads this lib folder.

clear indication that the exact version you want to use is part of what you should track alongside your source code.

> I assume there's a way to cache it so it doesn't rebuild constantly (some of these libraries are large and take a long time to build)

As long as files don't change, nothing needs to be rebuilt.

So, yeah, if your project depends on external libraries in specific, git submodules do sound kind of attractive.

Also note that other build systems (like meson) have a neater understanding of in-tree dependency projects, can check your system for an installed version of the dependency, and if not there in appropriate version, download, and if necessary, build themselves.

So, the second option is probably the easiest to maintain solution, as you said.

I, however, come from an free and open source background, and my users and their platforms are diverse, and Linux distros have strict guidelines about not packaging N copies of the same dependency. So, that would make it harder to upstream such packages to debian, Ubuntu, Fedora, Arch… . So, for me the situation is this: if there's a library that we want to use in a project, we define very clearly what the oldest version of that library is that would work. Within a release cycle, we **cannot** bump the required version.

So, say, we've released 2.0.0 of some software. The CMake files define which version of a library we support. "Releasing" software means that we guarantee to devs as well as to users that the next bugfix/feature extension versions in our 2.a.b series still build on the same systems – and that includes the same libraries that might be installed there. So, if 2.0.0 built on your computer, so will 2.0.1 and 2.9.0. Development that requires a new version of an external dependency can only happen on a git branch that's not meant for further 2.a.b releases, but targetting an eventual 3.0.0. When picking minimum dependency versions for that 3.0.0 release, we look what is commonly available on the operating systems we support. For example, if my timeline was that 3.0.0 be released within 2022 or 2023, that version would be the one available in Ubuntu 22.04LTS (because that will be an important system for our users for a long time, and also relatively conservative), also looking at the debian version most likely to be the current unstable (or stable, depending on what your target audience is), the RHEL version, the next Fedora, and what is currently available in our condaforge and macports repos.

Everything not available in tolerable versions through these standard packaging channels needs to be built locally anyway. Turns out that if you're not crazily progressive and don't try to support 5 year old Linuxes, the number of projects that you need to build locally is quite small.

On windows, you're basically handicapped by Microsoft's inability to provide a really sensible way of downloading packages of binary shared libraries that are actually shared between different application software. So, on Windows systems, you're down to either doing all your builds locally, or using a third-party way of distributing platform-dependent packages, like Conan.

No matter how you do it, you'd let your build fail as early as possible, with a clear indication that the library version found is not sufficiently new. CMake makes this easy; its `find_package` command takes a minimum version as argument.